# How to solve TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I do not get this error when I am compiling on VSC but when I load the page in my browser this is what I see:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

and:

```
  10 |   product={product}
  11 |   addToCart={props.addToCart}
  12 |   removeFromCart={props.removeFromCart}
> 13 |   cartItem={
     | ^  
  14 |     props.cart.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id === product.id)[0]
  15 |   }
  16 | />
```

Here is the full function:

```
function ProductListing(props) {
  return (
    <div className="product-listing">
      {props.products.map(product => (
        <ProductListItem
          product={product}
          addToCart={props.addToCart}
          removeFromCart={props.removeFromCart}
          cartItem={
            props.cart.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id === product.id)[0]
          }
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The error means that `props.cart` is `undefined`.

Comment: In other words, either you didn't pass `cart` as a prop to the element or the thing you did pass is `undefined`.

Comment: probably cart is not passed as a prop to ProductListing component or its not available in the initial render.

Comment: This is a very small example to understand where the problem is coming from. I saw that you are using redux on the Tags. Are you using mapStateToProps somewhere? Like the guys said, the cart is undefined. You need to trace the place where you are passing cart as props.

Comment: Ensure the prop exists before trying to filter it : `props.cart && props.cart.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id === product.id)[0]` but that may just move the issue in your `ProductListItem` we need more details about where that prop comes from

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in the parent you conditionally render the child so it's only rendered when the props.cart is ready.

```
export class ParentContainer extends Component {

    constructor(){
      super()
      this.state  = {
        cart: []
        isLoading: true
      }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
      // fetch('/some/endpoint')
      // massage your data and then push it to state
      .then(card => {
        this.setState({cart, isLoading: false})
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          {this.state.isLoading ? ( // evalutate if Data is ready to be passed
            <Fragment />
            ) : (
              <CartInformation cart={this.state.cart} />
            )
          }
        </Fragment>
      )
    }
  }
```